# Вопрос по созданию кортежей в 17-ом стандарте

Tags: linux, c++14, c++17, clang++, tuple

В обучающем видео, которое я смотрел, автор приводит такой код

```
std::tuple t{1, "Alisa"};
```

И для 17-ого стандарта все у него компилируется (visual studio, windows). Но у меня (clang++, linux) такой код выдает ошибку:

```
error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal
```

При этом если в аргументах инициализации я вместо строкового литерала указываю `string`

```
std::string a{"Alisa"};
std::tuple t{1, a};
```

то все работает. Почему так?

Comment: Не скажу по букве стандарта, но у вас инициализация типами `int` и `char[6]` - и вот этот массив ему при выводе и не нравится. Насколько это соответствует стандарту - не скажу... И, кстати, Visual C++ 2017 вообще не врубился в такой код - даже со `string`, требуя список аргументов шаблона `tuple`.

Comment: clang начиная с 5 и gcc начиная с 7 все делают.

Comment: @KoVadim у меня 5-й и ничего не делает.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, УМВР: https://godbolt.org/g/a7MJPy

Comment: @Fat-Zer ничего не понимаю: у меня clang 5-ой версии, этот же код не компилирует... Как так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строковый литерал `"Alisa"` - это массив символов, `char[6]`. Исходя из этого параметра вывести тип `std::string` невозможно.

Если вам нужен вывод типов для строк - нужно воспользоваться новым литералом строки (доступен с C++14):

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

std::tuple t{1, "Alisa"s};
```

Ну и, конечно же, не надо забывать про параметр командной строки `-std=c++17` (он общий для gcc и clang).

Comment: не помогло. строка с `string_literals` ничего не дала

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch обратите внимание: в моем ответе две строки с кодом, и обе отличаются от ваших

Comment: а, да, действительно. Не заметил `s` после строкового литерала. Спс